# Probability inequalities

Tags: st.statistics, pr.probability, inequalities

Hi everyone,

I am looking for some probability inequalities for sums of unbounded random variables. I would really appreciate it if anyone can provide me some thoughts.

My problem is to find an exponential upper bound over the probability that the linear combination of unbounded i.i.d. random variables, which are in fact the multiplication of two i.i.d. Gaussian, exceeds some certain value, i.e., $\mathrm{Pr}[\lvert X \rvert \geq \epsilon] \leq \exp(?)$, where $X = \sum_{i=1}^{N} \alpha_i w_iv_i$, $w_i$ and $v_i$ are generated i.i.d. from $\mathcal{N}(0, \sigma)$, and $0 \leq \alpha_i \leq 1$ is a coefficient.

I tried to use the Chernoff bound using moment generating function (MGF), but the derived bound was not so tight. The main issue in my problem is that the random variables are unbounded, and unfortunately I can not use the bound of Hoeffding inequality.

I will be to happy if you help me find some tight exponential bound .
Thanks in advance

Comment: Not clear what you're hoping to get here. Are you thinking of epsilon as small? In that case the probability will be close to 1/2 as $X$ will either be positive or negative (with equal probability); and will be close to 0 only with small probability. 

The probability of $|X|$ being less than $\epsilon$ should be about $\epsilon/\sqrt{\sigma N}$.


Comment: Let $w=(w_1,\dots,w_n)$ and $v=(v_1,\dots,v_n)$. By isotropy and independence between $w$ and $v$, $X$ has the same law as $<w,\|v\|_2e_1>$ which is $\|v\|_2w_1$. The law of $\|v\|_2$ and of $w_1$ are standard laws and the two r.v.\ are independent. Is it sufficient for your purpose ?

Comment: Dear Anthony, Thanks a lot for your answer but I need an upper bound over the probability not an approximate value.
Dear Cammomille, Thanks a lot for your answer
Unfortunately I did not understand what do you mean as ``law''.

Comment: law means distribution here. 

Comment: If I understood correctly, $X$ has the same distribution as $\lVert v \rVert_2 w$ whare $\lVert v \rVert_2$  has a chi distribution and $w_1$ has a Gaussian. Then, I can find the probability distribution of $X$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a standard exercise in large deviations. The exponential rate of decay for the large deviations of sums of i.i.d. random variables can be derived using Cramer's Theorem (see section 2.2 in Dembo and Zeitouni's book).

In the statement of the problem above, Cramer's theorem gives that 
$$P(|X| > \epsilon ) = e^{ - N I(\epsilon) + o(N) }, $$
where $I(x)$ is the large deviation rate function. In this example (unless I screwed up in my calculation)
$$ I(x) = \frac{1}{2}\left( \sqrt{1+4x^2}-1+\log(\sqrt{1+4x^2}-1)-\log(2x^2) \right) .$$

Comment: Cramer's theorem just gives exponential rate of decay. More precise asymptotics are 
$$P(|X| > \epsilon ) \sim \frac{C}{\sqrt{N}} e^{-N I(\epsilon)},$$ where the constant $C$ depends on $\epsilon$ and can be explicitly calculated in this case (see Theorem 3.7.4 in Dembo and Zeitouni's book). 

Comment: Farzad, in your comment above you mentioned that you needed an upper bound. An examination of the proof of the upper bound in Cramer's theorem shows that the exponential rate of decay given by the large deviation rate function is a strict upper bound. That is, 
$ P(|X| > \epsilon ) \leq e^{-N I(\epsilon)} $ for all $\epsilon>0$ and all $N\geq 1$. 

Comment: Thanks for your answer, can you give me the name of the book?

Comment: @Jon: *Strict upper bound* in the sense of *nonasymptotic upper bound*, I guess.

Comment: @Jon: Thanks a lot for your answer, but what about the case that we have a linear combination of RVs instead of the summation? I mean $X =\sum_{i=1}^{N} \alpha_i w_i v_i$, where $\alpha_i$ is deterministic. 

Comment: Maybe you should ask your question on http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Jon: The derived bound is exactly coincide with the Chernoff bound. I am wondering that there is any bound which is tighter than the Chernoff bound or Cramer's theorem!!!!

Comment: Farzad, I just noticed that I didn't read your question carefully enough. The bound I gave is correct if all of the $\alphi_i = 1/N$. If the random variables are i.i.d. with exponential moments this gives the correct rate of exponential decay. 

In order to get a good inequality, I would need to know more about the coefficients $\alpha_i$. For instance, if the $\alpha_i = 1/\sqrt{N}$ then the central limit theorem states that $|X|$ converges in distribution to a Normal random variable, in which case $P(|X|\geq \epsilon)$ won't decay exponentially. 



Comment: If the $\alpha_i$ coefficients decay fast enough that you expect exponential decay, then I would expect that they Chernoff bound is the best that you can do. To this end, it might also be useful to look at the Gartner-Ellis Theorem (Section 2.3 in "Large Deviations Techniques and Applications" by Dembo and Zeitouni). 

Comment: @ Jon, the coefficients are $\alpha_i=\rho^{i-1}$ where $0 \leq \rho < 1$, so as you expected they are decreasing exponentially. In this case, as I understood you think that the chernoff bound is the tightest and I can achieve better one!?

Comment: Actually, in this case the coefficients are decaying so fast, the infinite random sum $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \alpha_i w_i v_i$ actually converges almost surely. Therefore, $P(|X|>\epsilon)$ doesn't decay at all but converges to a non-zero constant. 